# Codeigniter group_by and Order_by conflict

Tags: codeigniter, group-by, sql-order-by

I am currently working on a Codeigniter query where I attemt to get a bunch of results. However, when I use both group_by and order_by within the same query, the order_by gets overruled and does not apply for some reason.

The query is the following:

```
$this->db->select('q.questionNumber, qa.qaId')->from('questions q');
$this->db->join('questionAnswers qa', 'qa.questionId = q.questionId');
$this->db->where('customerId', $customerId);
$this->db->order_by('q.questionNumber', 'desc');
$this->db->group_by('q.subject');
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use updated one

```
$this->db->select('q.questionNumber, qa.qaId')->from('questions q');
$this->db->select_max('q.questionNumber' , 'questionNumber'); // added this
$this->db->join('questionAnswers qa', 'qa.questionId = q.questionId');
$this->db->where('customerId', $customerId);
$this->db->order_by('q.questionNumber', 'desc');
$this->db->group_by('q.subject');
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your query :

```
$this->db->select('q.subject,COUNT(q.questionNumber), COUNT(qa.qaId)')->from('questions q');
$this->db->join('questionAnswers qa', 'qa.questionId = q.questionId');
$this->db->where('customerId', $customerId);
$this->db->group_by('q.subject');
$this->db->order_by('q.questionNumber', 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result();
```

Nessary to add column in selection row in query with Group By Clause and other field with aggregation function.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your query using this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT .....");

$query->result();
```

Comment: How would that fix the issue?

Comment: Write your query using basic SQL, maybe some how codeigniter is making an error in the query